# Close the Flowbite navbar dropdown on click of one of the links

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

Consider the default Flowbite navbar from the first example of here
https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/

On mobile devices, there is the burger menu. User has to click the burger menu button again to close the navbar dropdown. This is very inconvenient. My question is, how to close the navbar dropdown on click of one of the links?

Comment: In template, add ```@click="navbarClicked()``` to the nav. In `<script setup>`: ```let collapse = {};

onMounted(() => {
  createCollapseNav()
})

function createCollapseNav()
{
  const $targetEl = document.getElementById('navbar-default');
  const $triggerEl = document.getElementById('navbar-menu'); // ID of the hamburger
  collapse = new Collapse($targetEl, $triggerEl);
}

function navbarClicked(e)
{
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && !collapse._targetEl.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    collapse.collapse()
  }
}

```

Comment: Also remove ```data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default"``` from the hamburger. I believe this avoids the default Flowbite navbar expand/collapse flow from getting in the way which can cause a need to click the hamburger *twice* to expand again. Definitely a hack, but Flowbite navbar doesn't offer it out of the box nor in its API.